# Дублирование метода слушателя для разных пунктов списка

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview, ontouchlistener

Есть `ExpandableListView` в которому каждого  родительского(group) пункта есть несколько дочерних элементов группы(child).

У каждого дочернего элемента(child) есть элемент на который повешен `OnTouchListener`.

Если совершить свайп по одному дочернему пункту(вызывает анимацию и изменяет видимости элемента в макете дочернего пункта), то а потом пролистать список, то и у других пунктов (даже внутри одной группы) будет результат анимации.

Кто-нибудь знает как с этим бороться?

Comment: Вопрос не полный. Предоставьте код адаптера. Скорее всего лажа из-за непраильно запрограммированного адаптера

Comment: Да, лажа в адаптере. Спасибо за комментарий. Проблема была в том, что я забыл обнулять значения к исходному состоянию. Нужно в *getView()* ставить setVisiblity(View.GONE). Прочитал о том как работает ListView(наподобие ленты крутящейся по кругу). Проблему решил. еще раз спасибо.

Comment: Вы один из тех единственных людей, который воспользовавшись подсказкой решили проблему, а не стали дожидаться пока всё за вас сделают. Побольше бы таких прогеров

Answer (score 1, accepted):

от автора вопроса:

Проблема была в том, что я забыл обнулять значения к исходному состоянию.
Нужно в `getView()` ставить `setVisiblity(View.GONE)`.

Прочитал о том как работает `ListView` (наподобие ленты крутящейся по кругу)

Comment: Когда вы отвечаете за другого человека, хорошим тоном считается отметить ответ общим.